# Drop down button not working also not disappearing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have coded to make my menu button appear only in xs mode. It appears at every screen size. Also it doesn't drop down. I get error codes when I run it as shown below. I'm just a beginner. I can't make hide nor hair of this. I would appreciate any help at all.

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

The error readout:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
script.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery-1.11.3.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
index.html:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/CourseraProjects-master/module3solution/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at bootstrap.min.js:6
at bootstrap.min.js:6
at bootstrap.min.js:6
at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
script.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
index.html:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/CourseraProjects-master/module3solution/js/script.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

The status 404 Not found indicates that you is passing the wrong url of the resources or you don't have the resource in the right place, try another urls. The error in menu button probably occur because the resource are not loading.

In the last error apparently you're passing a HTML file when is expected JavaScript.